# @font-face rendering on remote desktop

Tags: css, fonts, remote-desktop

So here is the thing, we have a saas webapplication which uses a special font to display icons. So instead of using numerous png's we use a `<span>` with a class `icon`.

The CSS file starts with the @font-face tag, which was mainly generated by [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) and looks as follows:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'iconsregular';
    src: url('../../Content/fonts/icons-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../../Content/fonts/icons-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../../Content/fonts/icons-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../../Content/fonts/icons-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../../Content/fonts/icons-webfont.svg#iconsregular') format('svg');
         font-weight: normal;
         font-style: normal;
 }
```

This displays perfectly in all our supported browsers (IE7, 8, 9, FF, Safari & Chrome). But when the website is accessed through a remote desktop client. the webfont is not used. But the CSS file and .eot file *are* downloaded.

**Reproducing the error**

So I started testing and trying to reproduce the issue. When I took these steps, the error occurred:

1. Connect to Remote Desktop A (Server 2008)
2. Open IE9
3. Browse to the website
4. Fonts not shown.

Then I connected to a different server:

1. Connect to Remote Desktop B (Server 2008)
2. Open Firefox
3. Browse to the website
4. Fonts are shown!
5. Open website in IE9
6. Fonts are shown also, some goes for Chrome

After this surprise i reconnected to RD A again.

1. Open IE9
2. Fonts are shown...

It seems that the RDP client caches its fonts somewhere and at some time.

**When and how does this happen? And are there ways to force the RDP client in downloading and displaying @font-face webfonts?**

Comment: What do you mean by "But is downloaded and visible in the CSS."?

Comment: the CSS file and the .eot font file are downloaded.

Comment: Hey, I'm facing a similar issue I guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65801420/fonts-in-ie11-work-only-when-i-open-dev-console-and-re-enable-font-family-proper, did you find out the cause of the problem?

Comment: It's been 8 years. Since I couldn't figure it out at the time I think I ignored the issue and wasn't bothered by it again ;)